Did children get drafted into the British Navy during and before the Napoleanic war era such as in "Master and Commander?"
In the movie, Master and Commander: The Far Side of the World, on HMS Surprise, there are two teenagers who serving as officers and one child serving as an officer.
I am not sure if they (two teenagers and one child) are drafted into the Navy or they are of noble birth and volunteer into joining the Navy.
Either way, there was no age limit back then?

Actually there are four boy midshipmen - Calamy, Blakeney, Boyle and Williamson - though the latter two don't play any significant role in the story.

These are midshipmen

By the Napoleonic era (1793–1815), a midshipman was an apprentice officer who had at least nominally served at least three years as a volunteer, officer's servant or able seaman, and was roughly equivalent to a present-day petty officer in rank and responsibilities.

It was quite common for younger men to be midshipmen, I believe the minimum (official) age was 12

During the 19th century, changes in the training of naval officers in both the Royal Navy and the United States Navy led to the replacement of apprenticeship aboard ships with formal schooling in a naval college. Midshipman began to mean an officer cadet at a naval college. Trainees now spent around four years in a college and two years at sea prior to promotion to commissioned officer rank. Between the mid-19th and mid-20th centuries, time at sea declined to less than a year as the entry age was increased from 12 to 18.

It was also not unknown for "midshipmen" to be placed on a ships books well before the official age so that when the actually joined they seemingly already had recorded experience.

Since most midshipmen were from the gentry or had family connections with sailing ships, many used their connections to have their names placed on a ship's books. The practice, known colloquially as "false muster" was common even though it was technically illegal and frowned upon. This allowed some boys to be promoted to midshipmen, or in some cases lieutenant, without having completed the required amount of time at sea.


What's in that link seems quite at variance with a midshipman needing three years as a volunteer, officer's servant or able seaman, or being roughly equivalent to a present-day petty officer…
Who doubts Nelson, for instance, joined ship aged 12 with neither three-year history nor 'false muster' as, fictionally, did Horatio Hornblower at 17.
Petty officers are the navy's non-commissioned officers; up to the Army or Air Force rank of sergeant.
Chief petty officers are the navy's warrant officers; Army or Air Force sergeant majors.
I suggest as now, midshipmen ranked above all such.

No, boys were not drafted into the royal navy - as officers in training, that is.
The apprentice boy officers in training were all enlisted with the consent of their parents or legal guardians.  And sometimes at the order of their parents and legal guardians.  I supposed if you were on the dock watching a new boy boarding a ship for the first time, you might wonder whose idea it was to make a naval officer of him.
And of course I don't know what percentage of the time a boy wanted to join the navy and bugged his parents until they agreed to it, and what percentage of the time parents worried about the futures of their children decided to send a son to sea without his consent.
So there was no adult tyranny by the government forcing boys to become apprentice naval officers.  But possibly in some cases there was adult tyranny when parents forced a kid to "volunteer" to became an apprentice naval officer against his will.
I once read that for most of the 18th century the "young gentlemen" came from mostly middle-class backgrounds.  In 1778, King George III's third son, Prince William, joined the navy aged 13.  And that started a big increase in boys from the landed gentry and the titled aristocracy joining the navy and thus a higher prestige for naval officers.  Obviously Prince William's signing up needed the permission of his father, and possibly it was also at the instigation of his  father.  In this cause there certainly should be some sort of record of whose idea it was for the future King William IV to join the navy.
The Duchess of Richmond's famous ball at Brussels on June 15, 1815, was famously interrupted by a message that Napoleon had crossed the frontier into Belgium.  And I guess that few people at the ball were as worried by that interruption as the Duchess, with her husband and three of her sons members of the British army in Belgium.
Her Husband, the Duke of Richmond, Lennox, and Aubigny, was a British general in charge of the defenses of Burssels, but he left his post to observe the battles of Quatre-Bras and Waterloo, taking a risk he didn't need to.
Their oldest son, the 5th Duke, had been badly wounded in 1814 and was an aide-de-camp to the Prince of Orange and then to the Duke of Wellington during the Battle of Waterloo.
Their second son was an aide-de-camp to the Duke of Wellington in the Peninsula and at Waterloo.
Their fourth son was a staff officer at Waterloo while still 15 years old, but took no active part in the battle due to a horse accident, which cost him the sight in one eye.
Their third son, Lord Henry Lennox, (6 September 1797-25 February 1812) was not at Waterloo because he joined the Royal Navy instead.  As his ship HMS Blake sailed from Port Mahon, Menorca, Spain, he fell overboard and drowned, age 14.
https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Lennox-778
So if King George III had not already been declared insane and confined, the Duchess might have given him a piece of her mind for popularizing yet another way for her sons to risk their lives.
Of course officers in training were not the only boys aboard British Naval vessels.  A proportion of the enlisted sailors were also boys.  Ships crews were allowed a number of servants, who were usually boys.  Some "servants" were really "young gentlemen" and apprentice officers, but most were really servants of the officers.  In battle, small boys were preferred as "powder monkeys" to carry containers of gunpowder from the powder magazine to the guns, since the gun decks had low ceiling and were crowded with men during battle.
So beside the boy apprentice officers there were also boy apprentice enlisted sailors aboard ships of the line, who if they survived, would go on to become ordinary adult sailors and possibly rise in rank to be petty officers or warrant officers.
The Marine Society took homeless boys from the London streets and gave them basic education to make them ready to join the navy as servants.  They advertised for boys who wished to go to sea.
https://englishhistoryauthors.blogspot.com/2013/05/boy-sailors-during-age-of-nelson-and.html#:~:text=Many%2C%20such%20as%20the%20small,providing%20them%20with%20a%20classroom
So that implies that joining was voluntary for boys enlisting as ship's servants.
But in those days many criminals sentenced to hang for comparatively minor offenses were given the choice of serving n the army or the navy instead.  And I suppose that sometimes also applied to boy criminals.
"Impressment, colloquially "the press" or the "press gang", is a type of conscription of men into a military force, especially a naval force, via intimidation and physical coercion, conducted by an organized group (hence "gang")"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressment
During the 18th century and Napoleonic wars many British sailors were volunteers and many were impressed men.
"People liable to impressment were "eligible men of seafaring habits between the ages of 18 and 55 years""
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressment
So if those age limits were followed, boys would be in no danger of being impressed.  And I wonder how strictly the age limit was followed by press gangs.
Captain Hugh Pigott of HMS Hermione impressed many sailors from passing ships in 1797.  And perhaps not coincidentally the mutiny aboard Hermione on 21 September 1797 was the bloodiest in the history of the Royal Navy.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hermione_(1782)
According to Dudley Pope in The Black Ship (1988), one of the sailors on Hermione was only 14.  He had been a clerk in a merchant's office in the West Indies, and sent to conduct business on another island, perhaps because his boss figured he would be the smallest loss if anything happened to him. And his ship was captured by a French privateer.  Then the privateer was captured by a British ship and all the British sailors & passengers went free - no, many of them were impressed into the Royal Navy, including that landlubber boy, who became Captain Pigott's writer.
So that is one example of a boy impressed into the Royal Navy.  And I suspect there were thousands of other examples of boys being impressed.

The Duke of Clarence only became king through an accident of history; George IV's only child died young and George III's second son predeceased his brother. It was quite usual for younger sons of royal or landowning families to join the armed forces, and in the Navy you had to start young because there was so much technical stuff to learn. It seems extraordinary to us but it was quite normal at the time.
